# Javascript: Firefox, why this error?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am trying to make a firefox extension, and this is my very simple code:

```
var SlashUnblocker_Button = {

    //*************************************
        var prefManager = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);

        var prefs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefService);
        prefs.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch2);

        var alertsService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/alerts-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIAlertsService);

        var urlbar = window.content.location.href;
        prefManager.setCharPref("extensions.mf_unblocker.blocker_latest_url",urlbar);
        prefManager.setCharPref("extensions.mf_unblocker.blocker_latest_url_title",document.title);

    //*************************************    

1: function () {
    if(prefManager.getCharPref("extensions.mf_unblocker.blocker_user_email") != "a@a.com")
        { 

            gBrowser.selectedTab = gBrowser.addTab("chrome://mf_unblocker/content/1_options.html");
        }
        else
        {
              gBrowser.selectedTab = gBrowser.addTab("chrome://mf_unblocker/content/0_register.html");
        }
  },

test: function () {alert("testing!");}

}


window.addEventListener("load", function (e)
{
    SlashUnblocker_Button['test']();
}, false);
```

Here's the problem, see the part where I marked it with `//*********` ?
See the code inbetween.
If I put that code above the two functions it throws an error... but if I put it *in* function 1() then it works fine. The problem is I need to reference variable `prefManager` from both functions.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you add your var to the parent obj, and reference it from there inside function 1? `SlashUnblocker_Button.prefManager = ... ` and inside of 1:, `SlashUnblocker_Button.prefManager.getCharPref(...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaking, you are trying to put code into an object.

You should be putting it into a builder.

```
function SlashUnlockerButton(){

//*************************************
    this.prefManager = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);

    this.prefs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefService);
    prefs.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch2);

    this.alertsService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/alerts-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIAlertsService);

    this.urlbar = window.content.location.href;
    prefManager.setCharPref("extensions.mf_unblocker.blocker_latest_url",urlbar);
    prefManager.setCharPref("extensions.mf_unblocker.blocker_latest_url_title",document.title);

//*************************************    

this.1 = function () {
if(prefManager.getCharPref("extensions.mf_unblocker.blocker_user_email") != "a@a.com")
    { 

        gBrowser.selectedTab = gBrowser.addTab("chrome://mf_unblocker/content/1_options.html");
    }
    else
    {
          gBrowser.selectedTab = gBrowser.addTab("chrome://mf_unblocker/content/0_register.html");
    }
};

this.test = function () {alert("testing!");};
}

var SlashUnblocker_Button = new SlashUnlockerButton();
//...
```

I haven't tested it, but that's the idea.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing the `//***` section before `var SlashUnblocker_Button`?

Comment: No, but I think I have to have all my code encapsulated in my namespace like that if I want it to be approved to be hosted on the AMO site